# Html.Actionlink show wrong controller name when using with jquery tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I using Jquery tabs plugin to have tabs in my view.

I want `<li><a href="../JobDetails/Index/1234">JobDetails</a></li>` as my first tab.

For this I am doing

```
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("JobDetails",
                "Index",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "JobDetails",  // <-- Controller Name.
                  new { id = 1234 }
                )</li>
```

But I view source show me this link

```
<li><a href="/Coordination?Length=10" id="1234">JobDetails</a></li>
```

where Coordination is my controller name and I am having these tabs on Coordination controller and Action name(ViewName) is Index.

I am not sure why I am geting Controller name as Coordination even i name it as JobDetails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because you are using the wrong overloaded method.  Try this instead:

```
    <li>
    @Html.ActionLink
    (
        "JobDetails", 
        "Index",   // <-- ActionMethod 
        "JobDetails",  // <-- Controller Name. 
        new { id = 1234 },
        null // pass a null value for the htmlAttributes object
    )
    </li>
```

Your original overloaded method is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124.aspx):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

As you can see from the above parameter names, you are passing in "JobDetails" as your link text, so on and so forth.  That's why you're getting the rendered markup.

But by using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972.aspx) overload, you just need to pass `null` for the `htmlAttributes` object to get your desired markup:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Comment: +1 ActionLink is overloaded quite a bit.  Make sure to use the correct one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx

Comment: I found when using this particular overload of the `@Html.ActionLink` it was absolutely important to pass the following as instructed: `htmlAttributes: null // pass a null value for the htmlAttributes object` Otherwise it couldn't sort out the overload correctly.